# Dynamic Jqgrid options

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid that upon first load uses an ajax call to load based on a DB call.  Once it's been loaded, I store it in a JSON string and reload it from that when needed.  Rather than have 2 completely separate jqgrid definitions for the same thing, 1 for the Ajax call and 1 for the JSON data, is there a way I can set the following options dynamically?

Ajax call...

```js
url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Controller")',
datatype: "json",
postData: param1: "param1"
```

JSON call:

```js
datatype: "jsonstring",
datastr: sessionStorage.crmReportData,
```

basically, the rest of the JQGrid setup is the exact same for both, these are the only differences.  Is there a way I can use the first set of options on first load, and the 2nd set of options if the JSON string exists?

Comment: If you use [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net) you can use saveState and loadState methods. When the grid loads you can store it with save State and later you can use loadState to load the saved state. Here is [example](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/functionality/saveloadstate/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I correctly understand what you do. In the case you want to test `sessionStorage.crmReportData`. If it's not empty then you can to use `datatype: "jsonstring"` and to load the data from `sessionStorage.crmReportData`. Otherwise you wan to load the data from `url`. In the case you can use the following options:

```js
datatype: sessionStorage.crmReportData ? "jsonstring" : "json",
datastr: sessionStorage.crmReportData,
url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Controller")',
postData: { param1: "param1" },
```

The option `url` will be ignored if you use `datatype: "jsonstring"`. The parameter `param1` of `postData` should make no side effects if you use `datatype: "jsonstring"`. On the other side, the option `datastr` will be ignored in case of loading data from the server. Thus the above options should work.